# How to avoid being seen?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy

I'm curious, if I signed up for the new Jobs section of Stack Overflow and fill in my information presumably that opens me up to being found by other companies and people in their HR departments?

People can talk to recruiters/other companies discreetly but Stack Overflow is a big site, everyone uses it. What's to stop my current boss, client or colleague from stumbling across my CV and jumping to conclusions and making my current position difficult?

Comment: Nothing at all, that's just a risk you'd have to take if you want other employers to be able to find you. Unless you wanted to not be listed as looking.

Comment: [obligatory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifmRgQX82O4)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your CV is only visible according to the settings you choose. You can make it public to everyone, or you can make it visible only to employers who are Stack Overflow Careers customers with candidate search subscriptions. We do not display your job search status ("actively looking right now", "open, but not actively looking", and "not interested in jobs") publicly, ever. If you're actively or passively interested in jobs, you'll appear in search results in our candidate database product, and employers can see whether you're active or passive, but nobody else can. (If you say you're not interested in jobs, you don't show up in candidate search results, so our customers cannot see your CV unless you've set your CV to public and they have gotten a link elsewhere.)

Comment: Imagine, I'm looking for a different place to work. At the same time, if my current employer is a SO customer, and also has an open position and is looking for a candidate, then my CV can be found. Did I get this right, or there is some possibility to hide my CV from particular employers? Interesting... If I get my next job via SO Careers, it means that this company **is** definitely a SO customer. So, they will definitely see it when I start looking for the next job... Double-edged sword, isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

There is a privacy option to block you from appearing in searches.

Go to Jobs and select "edit CV". Then select "Settings" on the right. In there you can select a privacy option that you feel is appropriate.